# New-AzADAppCredential Generate Client Secret

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0

Is there a way to generate a password client secret using the New-AzADAppCredential cmdlet? I don't want to supply the password to the cmdlet and would much rather use the generate one much like the Azure Portal.

Comment: I'm afraid the documentation doesn't seem to suggest that it's possible. Can't you generate a Guid and supply it on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you can't, when using `New-AzADAppCredential` to create client secret, the `-Password` is needed.

The workaround is to use the [`New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) command in [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) module.

```
New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId "<object-id>"
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I was using before I moved to the Az module. I ended up reinstalling the AzureAD module just for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible now.

```
$Sub = "Your Sub Here"
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $Sub
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName 'MyTestApp'
$secretStartDate = Get-Date
$secretEndDate = $secretStartDate.AddYears(1)
$webApiSecret = New-AzADAppCredential -StartDate $secretStartDate -EndDate $secretEndDate -ApplicationId $app.AppId 
Write-Output $webApiSecret
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, but you can create a very similar client secret using the same tools that generate them in the portal.

It's not as elegant as having the solution baked into the cmdlet, but it works very well.

```
$bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
$rand = ([System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()).GetBytes($bytes)
$ClientSecret = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes) | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$endDate = [System.DateTime]::Now.AddYears(1)
New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId "<object-id>" -Password $ClientSecret -startDate $(get-date) -EndDate $endDate
```