# Powershell - New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal - getting secret property doesn't work?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

When i trying to run code below

```
$ServicePrincipalName = "MY SPN name"
$ScopeSubscriptionId = "Subscription ID"

$AzureAdApplication = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $ServicePrincipalName -HomePage "https://$ServicePrincipalName.local" -IdentifierUris "https://$ServicePrincipalName.com" -ErrorAction Stop

$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $AzureAdApplication.ApplicationId -Scope /subscriptions/$ScopeSubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
```

I'am unable to retrive secret property from "$sp" object. I totaly know that it's secret string and should be accesed like this:

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($sp.Secret)
$UnsecureSecret = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

When I delete ApplicationId parameter from second line, everything works correctly.

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $ServicePrincipalName -Scope /subscriptions/$ScopeSubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
```

Any ideas why it works like this? Although I observed that this behavior occurred on last days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you use the two commands below, it will not create the secret for you automatically.

```
$AzureAdApplication = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $ServicePrincipalName -HomePage "https://$ServicePrincipalName.local" -IdentifierUris "https://$ServicePrincipalName.com" -ErrorAction Stop    
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $AzureAdApplication.ApplicationId -Scope /subscriptions/$ScopeSubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
```

[image]

You could also check it in the portal:

[image]

When you use the command without `-ApplicationId` to create the service principal, it will create a service principal along with an AD App(App registration), and it will also create a secret for you automatically.

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $ServicePrincipalName -Scope /subscriptions/$ScopeSubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop
```

[image]

Check it in the portal:

[image]

---

If you want to use the command with `-ApplicationId`, you could create a secret for your AD App manually, you could use [`New-AzADAppCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-3.3.0), you can set the secret value yourself, in my sample, the secret is `password01!`.

```
$AzureAdApplication = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $ServicePrincipalName -HomePage "https://$ServicePrincipalName.local" -IdentifierUris "https://$ServicePrincipalName.com"
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $AzureAdApplication.ApplicationId -Scope /subscriptions/$ScopeSubscriptionId 

$SecureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password01!" -AsPlainText -Force
New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $AzureAdApplication.ApplicationId -Password $SecureStringPassword -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)
```

[image]

**Besides**, if you just want to generate the random value for the secret, you need to use [`New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0) in `AzureAD` module, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038203/new-azadappcredential-generate-client-secret/59042535#59042535).